# Return element of list as integer in Lisp

Tags: lisp

I'm supposed to write a function that will take in a list, extract the ID number from the list, and then return it as an integer (not a list).

My first function was pretty simple:

```
(defun idReturn2 (l) (if (eq (car l) '(ID)) (cadr l) (idReturn list)))
```

Which I called with the function:

```
 (idReturn2 '((name (light bulb)) (mfgr ge) (watts 60) (id 357) (quantity 6)))
```

The method is supposed to return 357, but instead returns (357). It's the right number to return, but it's part of a list, which my professor outright told us not to do.

I noticed that my quadratic equation function only returned an integer without the parentheses, so I thought I could parse the integer using parse-integer:

```
(defun idReturn2 (l) (if (eq (car l) '(ID)) (parse-integer (cadr l)) (idReturn list)))
```

Still returns (357). I've gone over my lisp notes a dozen times, as well as the slides, and I can see absolutely no way to pull the data out of the list. Could anyone offer me some guidance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have a list `((property-name1 value1) (property-name2 value2) ...)` if that list is given as argument `l` then `(car l)` isn't `(property-name1)` but `(property-name1 value1)`. Luckily you see that the symbol you should check is in the results first element and that means you should use `(car (car l))` or `(caar l)` for short. `(eq (caar l) 'property-name1) ; ==> t`

Notice that when you don't find it in the first iteration you call a totally different function `IdReturn`, not with the rest of `l` but a different variable `list` (whatever that is). You haven't supplied it so I cannot tell how you get `(357)` but it's not from functions supplied in your question.

PS: Any list `(a)` `(a b)` or `(a b c)` you pull the first value with `car`. `(car '(357)) ;==> 357`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the IDReturn. I was being dumb and calling an old function, which what was causing about 90% of my problems. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's less confusing if you use the `first`, `second` and `rest` functions:

```
(defun idReturn (l) 
  (when l
    (let ((c (first l)))
      (if (eq (first c) 'id)
        (second c) 
        (idReturn (rest l))))))
```

which is the same as

```
(defun idReturn (l) 
  (when l
    (let ((c (car l)))
      (if (eq (car c) 'id)
        (cadr c) 
        (idReturn (cdr l))))))
```

then

```
? (idReturn '((name (light bulb)) (mfgr ge) (watts 60) (id 357) (quantity 6)))
357
? (idReturn '((name (light bulb)) (mfgr ge) (watts 60) (idx 357) (quantity 6)))
NIL
```

Note that, using `assoc`, you can simplify the function to

```
(defun idReturn (l)
  (second (assoc 'id l)))
```